# A continuous surjection is proper if and only if pre-images of compact sets are compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, closed-map

> **Dugundji's Definition:** A map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is called ***perfect*** (or ***proper***), if it is a closed continuous surjection such that each fiber $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, $y\in Y$, is compact.

Show that a continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is proper if, and only if, $f^{-1}(K)\subset X$ is compact, whenever $K\subset Y$ is compact.

My try:

> $(\Rightarrow)$ We need just to show that $K\subset Y$ compact $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(K)\subset X$ compact. Let $K\subset Y$ be a compact set and let $\scr U$ be an open convering of $f^{-1}(K)$. Then $\scr F$$=\{F_U\,:\, U\in \scr U\}$, $F_U:=X-U$, is a family of *closed* sets. Since $f$ is closed, $\scr V$$=\{Y-f(F_U)\,:\,U\in \scr U\}$ is a family of open subsets of $Y$. But... what then?
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ It is obvious that each fiber $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact, since every $\{y\}\subset Y$ is compact. Let $F\subset X$ be closed. How can I show that $f(F)\subset Y$ is closed? (in order to show that $f:X\to Y$ is closed)

Comment: I don't suppose $X,Y$ are assumed to be Hausdorff?

Comment: It may be empty of course. Take some $U=X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's distinguish the definitions:

A continuous map is **perfect** if it is a closed surjection with compact fibers.

A continuous map is **proper** if the preimage of each compact set is compact.

The forward direction, perfect => proper, holds in full generality. 
Going with your notation, we can assume $\mathcal U$ is closed under finite unions. This means each fiber is covered by some $U\in\mathcal U,$ and hence each $k\in K$ is covered by some open set in $\mathcal V.$ By compactness of $Y$ some  finite union of sets in $\mathcal V$ covers $Y,$ which can only come from a finite cover of $f^{-1}(K)$ by sets in $\mathcal U.$

The backward direction does not hold in general, for example the constant map from the one-point space (or any compact space) to the open point of the Sierpinski space is proper but not closed. It does hold when $Y$ is compactly generated Hausdorff: [Continuous proper map into compactly generated Hausdorff space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632650/continuous-proper-map-into-compactly-generated-hausdorff-space-is-closed).

Comment: Other examples of a proper non-closed map: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1347806/4280) or even simpler [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/966258/4280).